# unable to insert object into collection in monogoDB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

i am trying to insert an object into a database collection in Mongodb from C# .Net Core. It keeps giving me this error and i dont know what to do anymore, please help.

Object Class:

```
 [BsonDiscriminator("Company")]
public class Company
    {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("CompanyId")]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("AccountNumber")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("BankId")]
        public int BankID { get; set; }
    }
```

Database connection class:

```
 public class DatabaseConnection
{
    static string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    public  DatabaseConnection()
    {

    }

    public IMongoDatabase DatabaseConnect()
    {

        return new MongoClient(connectionString).GetDatabase("FlourishDB");
    }


}
```

Action Class:

```
 public static void AddIntoDatabase(this Object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            IMongoCollection<Company> symbolcollection = new DatabaseConnection().DatabaseConnect().GetCollection<Company>("Company");

            Company c = (Company)obj;
            symbolcollection.InsertOne(c);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Console Line:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Company() { AccountNumber = "101010" }.AddIntoDatabase();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed succesfully");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Error Message achieved:
 Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Why aren't you using entity framework? It's pretty solid for basic operations.

Comment: I was given the task to complete without the use of entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine with MongoDB Driver of latest 2.5.0 version. However I get the same error when using versions prior to 2.4.0.

So to fix your problem, upgrade used version of MongoDB driver to 2.4.0 or 2.5.0.